# Entitykey values cannot be changed once they are set

Tags: entity-framework

I have a method for editing a table (Human) in my database. That table is part of a 1 to many relationship. Human is on the many side.
Human has a foreign key named idOtherTable.

Now, here is how I'm trying to change it:

```
Employee e = (from x in db.Human
              where x.idHuman == someNumber
              select x).First();

            e.name = name;
            e.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            //this is how I try to change it:
            e.RoleReference.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value = editEmployee.idRole;
```

but it says that once is set, the value cannot be changed. How can I resolve this?